# Matching across a line vs matching words regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Why is it that when I match across new lines it would seem that I can't identify individual words. For example:

```
content = "COAL_STORIES
AUSTRALIA - blah blah blah
BOTSWANA – blah blah blah 

URANIUM_STORIES 
AUSTRALIA – blah
INDIA - blah

COPPER_STORIES
AUSTRALIA - blah blah blah
AUSTRALIA - blah blah blah
CHINA - blah blah blah

ALUMINIUM_STORIES"




sections = content.scan(/\w.*_.*\b/)
```

Give and array:

```
[
    [0] "COAL_STORIES",
    [1] "URANIUM_STORIES",
    [2] "COPPER_STORIES",
    [3] "ALUMINIUM_STORIES"
]
```

But if I try that using the 'm' flag everything gets matched:

`sections = content.scan(/\w.*_.*\b/m)` gives an array:

```
[
    [0] "COAL_STORIES\nAUSTRALIA - blah blah blah\nBOTSWANA – blah blah blah \n\nURANIUM_STORIES \nAUSTRALIA – blah\nINDIA - blah\n\nCOPPER_STORIES\nAUSTRALIA - blah blah blah\nAUSTRALIA - blah blah blah\nCHINA - blah blah blah\n\nALUMINIUM_STORIES"
]
```

As far as I can tell I'm still looking for the same word boundaries?

Comment: Quantifiers like `*` are by default greedy, `.` means all characters (including newlines with the m modifier). This is why the `\b` is the last of the string. So you obtain the longest result.

Comment: Since the first method seems to work, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well it will work fine with the line breaks, as there will always be line breaks in the correct places. Regex always seems to give me surprising results at the moment, so I'm trying to get a better understanding

Comment: I am actually going to need to match as if there were no line breaks...

Comment: Without line breaks, you can try something like this: `\b\w+?_\w+\b` but it can be a little risky if other words contain underscores.

Comment: Thanks, there shouldn't be any underscores in the text and I'll get an error if there are. That is a great help

Comment: My mistake, the last `\b` is useless, remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on Casimir's comment:

`.*` is greedy... it will match the longest possible string it can, including newlines if you let it (which you can/did do by enabling multiline matching with `\m`).

In your first example `.*` will not match newlines, so `\b` is forced to match a word boundary on the same line as where `\w` matched.

In your second example `.*` will match across lines, so when `\w` matches your first character, `\b` is free to match any word boundary, even many lines away, as long as there's an `_` somewhere between the two. Specifically, for you, it looks like:

- `\w` matched the first character in your input: "C" from "COAL_STORIES"
- `.*` matched everything up to "ALUMINUM" on the last line
- `_` matched "_"
- `.*` matched "STORIES"
- `\b` matched the end of "STORIES"

Comment: I am actually going to need to match as if there were no line breaks. Do you know how I would go around doing this?

Comment: You'd have to be a bit more specific about what you're looking for, but maybe something like /[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+/ which captures every uppercase-only word with one underscore in it?